# How to determine array in class?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a class like this:

```
class Zmogus
{

    public string Vardas { get; set; }
    public int Draugu_Kiekis { get; set; }
    public string[] Draugas { get; set; }


    public Zmogus(string vardas, int draugu_Kiekis, string[] draugas)
    {

        Vardas = vardas;
        Draugu_Kiekis = draugu_Kiekis;
        Draugas = draugas;

    }

    public Zmogus()
    {

    }
}
```

And i would like to know how to determine the size of it, because when i use it like this:

```
zmogus.Draugas[i] = parts[i+2];
```

It just shows me that the "Draugai" parameter is null.

Comment: Just have another property DraugasCount or appropriately named property. That returns the length of the array?

Comment: Null is different than size. You should always null check (== null) , then length check (Draugas.Length)

Comment: No i just have a container class that determines the amount of that other class

Answer (score 2):

Add the property:
`public int DraugasLength{get  {return this.Draugas.Length} set;}`
or just use `Draugas.Length`. I think that behavior you are looking for is more like list than array - I would recommend using List from System.Collections.Generic instead of arrays.